# Adventure Travel: Where should I go in India to experience staying in a forest?

Tags: budget, india, safety, nature-and-wildlife, adventure

Myself and my friends are planning to stay inside a forest for a night and want to feel that experience during the mid of September. In INDIA, is there any places where I can get that amazing experience.?

Comment: @pnuts the context is : wanna stay in a house(bamboo house/wood house) inside a forest and have a sight seeing inside the forest at day time.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of options available, subject to accommodation availability and the season.
Since you plan for September, I deliberately eliminate major wildlife sanctuaries since possibilities of getting permits done are rare.

1. Agumbe. State: Karnataka.
2. Koyna Nagar. State: Maharashtra.
3. Tadoba Wildlife Sanctuary. State: Maharashtra.
4. Mudumalai. State: Tamilnadu.
5. kareri Lake Campsites near Shimla. State: Himachal Pradesh.
6. Coorg. State: Karnataka.
7. Bamnoli near Satara. State: Maharashtra.
8. Amboli. State: Maharastra.
9. Tapola near Mahabaleshwar. State: Maharashtra.

and so on.. The list doesn't end.